# Strict Aliasing do c

Tags: c

**Galera gostaria que alguem podesse me explicar essa tal de Strict Aliasing , e com exemplos de cast , vi em um livro mais não  entendi direito.**

Comment: Coloque o exemplo do livro em seu enunciado.

Answer (score 2):

Strict aliasing é quando o compilador presume que dois ponteiros diferentes não apontam para a mesma área de memória. É uma presunção criada no padrão C99 que visa melhoria de performance.

Por exemplo, a função memcpy(dst, src, n) copia "n" bytes a partir da posição "src" para a posição "dst". Esta função poderia funcionar de forma muito mais eficiente se garantidamente as duas áreas de memória (dst[0..n] e src[0..n]) não se sobrepõem.

Porque, se elas se sobrepõem, a cópia teria de começar por um lado ou por outro, conforme a situação. Se dst > src, a cópia pode começar a partir da posição zero, por outro lado se dst < src, a cópia tem de começar do final e andar para trás. Ainda tem os casos dos dois buffers serem completamente sobrepostos (dst = src).

Tudo isso tornava a implementação do memcpy() mais lenta. O C99 estabeleceu a regra do strict aliasing, que permite ao compilador presumir que os ponteiros não são patológicos, ou seja, não se sobrepõem. Com isso, o memcpy() pode ser o mais rápido possível (se a CPU copia mais rápido de trás para frente, é assim que será feito).

Outra situação típica é quando dois ponteiros de tipos diferentes apontam para uma mesma área da memória. Por exemplo, um ponteiro para uma estrutura qualquer, e outro ponteiro int* para a mesma estrutura. Talvez a ideia do programador seja ler o conteúdo da estrutura inteiro por inteiro.

Mas, pela regra do strict aliasing, o compilador não precisa presumir que ambos os ponteiros cobrem a mesma coisa, o que pode causar todo tipo de comportamento estranho. Para estabelecer da forma correta que dois ponteiros de tipos diferentes apontam para a mesma memória, deve-se usar um "union".

Answer (score 0):

Se eu não estou errado, **Strict Aliasing** refere-se a passagem de valores de variáveis ou `struct` entre si de tipos diferentes. Ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
        short x;
        short y;
}strc_int;

void main(){
    strc_int *sint = malloc(sizeof(strc_int));
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));;
    char num[] = {4,1,140,10};

    memcpy(sint,num,4);
    
    x = (int*) sint;

    printf("%d - %d\n",sint->x, sint->y);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

> O que está acontecendo?

`sint`, `x`, e `num` possuem o mesmo tamanho(4 bytes), então não tem problema eu passar os valores de um para o outro.

Isso só é possível porque os valores possuem estruturas.

```
`char`     ocupa 1 byte  []
`short`    ocupa 2 bytes [][]
`int`      ocupa 4 bytes [][][][]
`strc_int` ocupa 4 bytes [][][][]
```

Se não os espaços não fossem alocados corretamente, com certeza daria erro de memória.

Muitos programadores usam essa pratica, alguns sem saber que tem até um nome específico (Como era o meu caso).

Mas acho que não é uma boa prática para programadores inexperientes, pois erros em relação a memória, são os piores para se resolver.

## Referencia

**[Cell Performace](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)**

**[Blog Qt](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/)**

**[Thiemonagel](http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/no-strict-aliasing/)**

**[Blog Regehr](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959)**